# Android let icon disappear if screen is smaller than 400px

Tags: android, screen

I'm looking for a way to let an icon oder a title (textview) disappear if the screen is smaller than 400px. At the moment I'm programming an android app and i want to let the self-made header disappear on smaller screen.

Thx for your help in advance.

Comment: Don't use pixels. Huawei Watch is 400px. I doubt your items would fit in it's screen.

Comment: I have an icon with text on the right of the icon. i want to let the text disappear von small Smartphones or something like that. At this moment I tried nothing, because I am new to android programming and learning by doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get your question right,
u can do the following:

In your `onCreate` check the users screen width:

```
DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
int screenWidthInPix= displayMetrics.widthPixels; //Screen width in px

if(screenWidthInPix < 400){
    //Remove your header, or stuff u want to remove
}
```

Hope this helps u out.

Comment: Thank you, I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to do in the content of the screen, pls use different XML layout file, you can show/hide what you want with smaller screen size by defining in layout folder such as layout-320sw, layout-400sw, ...
Or a simpler way is calculating screen width then hide the icon.

Comment: That sounds really useful. Thanks for the fast answer.